# Does Selenium have a function to check triggering/visibility of required field warning messages in HTML?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing automated QA on a webpage.

How to see, using Python selenium, if this message is show to me? (HTML code)
`required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password cannot be blank')`

I have tried using the is_displayed() function which comes with selenium, but it did not work. This is the code I tried (python): `if Message.is_displayed() != 0 : print("Message shown!")`

is_displayed() returns a Boolean value, in my case- always false since it does not find the message.